# .htaccess force https but only one page with http or https

Tags: http, redirect, ssl, https

i want to redirect all pages to https excluding one page!

This page **www.domain.com/data/push-send** should accessible over http:// or https://

This is my current code:

```
RewriteEngine On

# Redirect external .php requests to extensionless url
RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} ^(.+)\.php([#?][^\ ]*)?\ HTTP/
RewriteRule ^(.+)\.php$ /$1 [R=301,L]

# enforce a no-trailing-slash policy
RewriteRule ^(.*)/$ /$1 [L,R=301]

# Redirect api to data/push-send
RewriteRule ^api$ data/push-send [qsappend,L]

# no index in URL
RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} ^[A-Z]{3,9}\ /index\.php\ HTTP/
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://www.domain.com [L,R=301]
RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} ^[A-Z]{3,9}\ /index\ HTTP/
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://www.domain.com [L,R=301]

# force https
RewriteCond %{SERVER_PORT}   !^443$
RewriteRule  (.*)  https://%{HTTP_HOST}/$1   [R=301,qsappend,L]
```

How i can do that

Thanks Kevin

Answer (score 0):

i got it by my self

```
# force https
RewriteCond %{SERVER_PORT}   !^443$
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !data/push-send [NC]
RewriteRule  (.*)  https://%{HTTP_HOST}/$1   [R=301,qsappend,L]
```

Kevin